# Increase the notification interval for Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

`Google Calendar` events are generating notifications 10 minutes in advance - but I would prefer longer e.g 30 or 60. How can that be configured?   There is not any such setting under `Settings | Notifications` .. which surprised me

[image]

I am on `macOS Monterey`

Comment: Calendar notifications are not configured on a global level, instead each calendar entry can have it's individual notification/reminder time.

Comment: @Robert  While that may be true, it makes little sense to me because most of my calendar entries are created automatically e.g off of invites from coworkers

Comment: Even if the calendar entries are created automatically you can still edit all of them later and change the reminder time.

Comment: In addition to extra effort that's unreliable: have to have time to do it on the spot or try to remember later . Goes back to : this is quite a surprise not to be an available configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've been looking at settings that apply to all your calendars. Instead, try adjusting the settings for a specific calendar as follows:

1. Start with the settings screen that you shared (by going to [calendar.google.com](https://calendar.google.com/), clicking the gear icon, and then clicking `Settings`)
2. Scroll down to "Settings for my calendars". Click on the calendar that you're interested in.
3. Scroll down to "Event notifications". I expect it shows the 10 minute notification that you're looking to change. Remove that notification, then click `+ Add notification` and add a longer one.
4. Repeat for any other calendars that you're interested in.